# SwiftUI Textfield auto add hyphens for date input

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

While entering the date in a SwiftUI Textfield I want to avoid manual input of hyphens - within the format YYYY-MM-DD so that I only have to type in the numbers and the hyphens are automatically added.

So add a hyphen after the first 4 digits, then after the next two digits.

A total of two hyphens to separate the year-month-date.

I have read some older articles to do this for UIKit but haven’t been able to find instructions for SwiftUI.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Why not a Date Picker? declare your date var `@State private var date = Date()` and in your View body  `DatePicker("date:", selection: $date, displayedComponents: [.date])`

Comment: use onChanged on your TextField and when the user types in something add the hyphens when needed. Though bare in mind, that if you do so, the user will expect same behavior for removing characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution but the date formatting is in US style MM-DD-YYYY

```
struct DobScreen: View {
@State private var dobText: String = ""
@State var textLen = 0

var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField("MM-DD-YYYY", text: $dobText)
            .onChange(of: dobText) { newValue in
                
                if newValue.count < textLen {
                    // If the length of the new value is less than the previous length,
                    // it indicates a deletion (backspace).
                    dobText = ""
                    textLen = 0
                    return
                }
                // Check if the input length exceeds 10 characters
                 guard newValue.count <= 10 else {
                     dobText = String(newValue.prefix(10))
                     return
                 }
                
                 // Handle backspace
                 if newValue.count < dobText.count {
                     // If the length of the new value is less than the previous length,
                     // it indicates a deletion (backspace).
                     dobText = ""
                     return
                 }
                 
                 // Add separators for MM - DD - YYYY format
                 if newValue.count >= 2 && !newValue.contains("-") {
                     dobText.insert("-", at: dobText.index(dobText.startIndex, offsetBy: 2))
                 }
                 if newValue.count >= 5 && !newValue[dobText.index(dobText.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)...].contains("-") {
                     dobText.insert("-", at: dobText.index(dobText.startIndex, offsetBy: 5))
                 }
                textLen = dobText.count
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```